# iOS Swift4 - reInitialize lazy variable

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-initialization

Is there a way to reInitialize lazy variable based on the current language ?

```
lazy var localizableDictionary: NSDictionary! = {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(
        forResource: "Localizable",
        ofType: "strings",
        inDirectory: nil,
        forLocalization: Localizer.shared.currentLanguage)
    else {
        fatalError("Localizable file NOT found")
    }

    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a `lazy var` clearly its a variable, so Swift will not stop you from modifying its value at any point in time if thats necessary.

You can simply say at any point,

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(
    forResource: "Localizable",
    ofType: "strings",
    inDirectory: nil,
    forLocalization: Localizer.shared.currentLanguage)
    else {
        fatalError("Localizable file NOT found")
}
self.localizableDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

**FYI**

> Lazy initialization (also sometimes called lazy instantiation, or lazy
>   loading) is a technique for delaying the creation of an object or some
>   other expensive process until it’s needed. When programming for iOS,
>   this is helpful to make sure you utilize only the memory you need when
>   you need it.

above quote copied from http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/

Please don't be under the impression that lazy var are constants if you really need a constant you will opt for let straight away :)

Hope it helps

Comment: @Anas Alhasani : am glad I could be of some help :) happy coding :)